# Problem in updating database (jdbc)

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm developing an application in which I dynamically create forms by reading data from a database. What I want is the user to be able to update or delete the database by using the corresponding button in the database(I am allowing user to connect to almost any database so I have no idea about the type of columns, or whether an update will be supported). I've successfully created code to insert data in any database but I am struggling to figure out a way to update and delete records. This is the code snippet for the class for updating/deleting :

```
/* tflist contains the list of text fields(I used setName() to set their names to
   the column names in the table) which I created dynamically
   for allowing the user to enter new values and they already hold the
   current values,panel contains all the labels and generated gui which is basically
   column name in a label and text field, 
   e.g. Roll no(label) : 9(in a text field), 
   tablename has the name of the table, 
   jtable is the table on which event occurred
   (you click on a row of table, and a form appears that gives you the option to
    update or delete something),and rowno contains the row number of jtable on which
    the user clicked */



private void update_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:



    String querypart2=" WHERE ";

        for(int i=0;i<tflist.size();i++)
          {                  
             JTextField tf=tflist.get(i);

             if(tf.getText()!=null&&!tf.getText().equals(""))
             {          



              if(jtable.getValueAt(rowno, i)==null||jtable.getValueAt(rowno, i).equals(""))
              {
                 querypart2=querypart2+"\""+tf.getName()+"\" IS NULL";                            
              }
              else
              {
                  querypart2=querypart2+"\""+tf.getName()+"\"='"+jtable.getValueAt(rowno,i)+"'";     
              }                             

              querypart2=querypart2+" AND ";


             }


          }

           if(querypart2.equals(" WHERE "))
           {
               querypart2="";
           }
           else
           {
               querypart2=querypart2.substring(0, querypart2.length()-5);
           }


       try {

        Statement statement = Aw_supersensible.conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM \""+tablename+"\""+querypart2);  

        rs.absolute(1);


       for(int i=0;i<tflist.size();i++)
         {    
            JTextField tf=tflist.get(i);                
            rs.updateObject(tf.getName(), tf.getText());              
         }

       Aw_supersensible.conn.commit();

        for(int i=0;i<tflist.size();i++)
         {    
            JTextField tf=tflist.get(i);
            jtable.setValueAt( tf.getText(),rowno,i);
            rs.updateRow();                   
         }

        central_window.cw.setEnabled(true);
        dispose();

         }
         catch(final Exception e)
        {                          
                     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                     public void run() {
                     new errorWindow(new javax.swing.JFrame(),e.toString()).setVisible(true);
                       }
                     });
        }



}

private void delete_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String querypart2=" WHERE ";

        for(int i=0;i<tflist.size();i++)
          {                  
             JTextField tf=tflist.get(i);

             if(tf.getText()!=null&&!tf.getText().equals(""))
             {          



              if(jtable.getValueAt(rowno, i)==null||jtable.getValueAt(rowno, i).equals(""))
              {
                 querypart2=querypart2+"\""+tf.getName()+"\" IS NULL";                            
              }
              else
              {
                  querypart2=querypart2+"\""+tf.getName()+"\"='"+jtable.getValueAt(rowno,i)+"'";     
              }                             

              querypart2=querypart2+" AND ";


             }


          }

           if(querypart2.equals(" WHERE "))
           {
               querypart2="";
           }
           else
           {
               querypart2=querypart2.substring(0, querypart2.length()-5);
           }


       try {

        Statement statement = Aw_supersensible.conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM \""+tablename+"\""+querypart2);  
        rs.absolute(1);

        rs.deleteRow();

        ((DefaultTableModel)jtable.getModel()).removeRow(rowno);

       Aw_supersensible.conn.commit();

       central_window.cw.setEnabled(true);
       dispose();
       }
        catch(final Exception e)
        {                          
                     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                     public void run() {
                     new errorWindow(new javax.swing.JFrame(),e.toString()).setVisible(true);
                       }
                     });
        }

}
```

Comment: That's not a *snippet* - it's nearly 300 lines of code. If you're having a problem with database operations, *just present the database part* (ideally still in a short but complete program). We don't want to have to wade through UI code to find the bit which is actually causing a problem.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is separate your client side code and your database (sql) code.

Comment: @PeterSmith I could just show the database part, but understanding it might be difficult for the reader

Comment: I'm now editing it just to show the update and delete button codes, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @Qwerky: This was my first post, please help me out guys, you've rated my post as -2! does that mean my question is pointless?

Comment: @PeterSmith   This was my first post, please help me out guys, you've rated my post as -2! does that mean my question is pointless?

Comment: @Ankur  This was my first post, please help me out guys, you've rated my post as -2! does that mean my question is pointless?

Comment: Any takers for this question? At first I was excited about the quick response(probably the quickest) but now, I'm thinking about moving my question to another forum :(

Comment: Not necessarily, it means it cannot be answered based on what you have provided. The first thing you should do is separate the different layers of your application. Put the swing classes together, the database access classes together and the java objects that describe your system together. Then you can show everyone what your database code is (without all the other stuff) and they can help you with that. You should also look at Unit Testing (I would recommend TestNG). This will help you test individual components and pick up errors like this more easily.

Comment: @Ankur : I built my application using modular approach only, testing individual units , and that's why I know the problem is with my approach to update the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is some pseudo code for your `delete` operation, to show you what I think a 'modular' approach would look like.

I am not an experienced developer (in fact I am not a developer), so there may be better ways.

```
private void delete_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

 String tableName; 
 List<String> whereProperties;
 List<String> whereValues;

  // get your table name
  // get your properties and values from the GUI in such a way that the property in whereProperties.get(n) corresponds to the value in whereValues(n)

// have a function in some class (I've called it SQL) that can take the following parameters and performs the delete operation.

   SQL.delete(tableName, whereProperties, whereValues);

}
```